# how to replace gradle file with offline jar file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, jcenter

I have a ARtoolKit augmented reality application and when i open this project, in gradle.build write below code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}

unfortunately in my country we can not sync gradle online, so i download "gradle-experimental-0.2.1.jar" then how i can replace this file in the above gradle.build file?

> how i can replace gradle-experimental-0.2.1.jar file in the above gradle.build file?

Comment: What does "cannot sync gradle online" mean?  If you can't reference a remote repo, you could store it in a local directory and specify a "flatDir" repository.  Read the user guide for info about how to do that.

Comment: i can not sync gradle with remote repository therefore i must use local file to solve dependency,can you say more explation ?